# Google Realtime API update model from JSON

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm having trouble utilising the `/realtime/update` rest resource. I can successfully make the request as specified in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/update) and i get a 204 status response with no body. Which is expected. However the realtime model in my application does not change in anyway. Am I missing something on how the resource works?

```js
this.updateRealtimeWithRevision = function (fileId, revisionId) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var onComplete = function (result) {
    deferred.resolve(result);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  };

  // get revision content...
  this.load(fileId, revisionId).then(function(data){

    var json = angular.toJson(data);

    var request = {
      'path': '/upload/drive/v2/files/' + fileId + '/realtime',
      'method': 'PUT',
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      'params': {
        'uploadType': 'media'
      } ,
      'body': json
    };

    console.log(request);

    gapi.client.request(request).then(
      function(resp){
        console.log("fullfilled");
        console.log(resp);
      },
      function(resp){
        console.log("reject");
        console.log(resp);
      }
    );

  });

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the correct app id to to make the request?  You could verify by doing a get, using the same credentials and doc id: do you get the document you expect?

Comment: @CherylSimon can confirm GET /drive/v2/files/<fileID>/realtime does work, and the response contains the real-time model. Also worth noting the PUT request has a 'result' property in the json which is FALSE.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but you are sure that you are providing modified json?

Comment: @CherylSimon Yes the json is definitely different.

Comment: +1 for example code which actually does work for me. Finding any useful documentation on the realtime update REST API (or even gapi.client.request) is like hunting fish with feet. And shoes.

Comment: Also +1 for this example, can confirm that it works for me (event if documentation confusingly says "Do not supply a request body with this method.") One thing I'm interested in is whether this API will be available after the RealTime API officially retires in 2019.